# Compiling Pango with Stack

Tags: haskell, gtk, preprocessor, haskell-stack, pango

I've been trying to compile a Haskell project which depends on Pango (via Gtk3), so far without success. The issue *seems* to be with the preprocessor (based on odd mangled type names), but I have yet to find the exact cause.

I'm using `stack` on a **64-bit** machine running **Windows 10** and **GHC 7.10**. I've compiled other projects using Gtk3 with `cabal` - on the same PC - so I'm fairly certain it's not a compatibility issue.

I've included a small portion of the build log below.

```
[1 of 2] Compiling Gtk2HsSetup      ( Gtk2HsSetup.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Gtk2HsSetup.o )
[2 of 2] Compiling Main             ( SetupMain.hs, dist\setup-wrapper\Main.o )
Linking dist/setup-wrapper\setup.exe ...
Configuring pango-0.13.1.0...
Building pango-0.13.1.0...
Preprocessing library pango-0.13.1.0...
[ 1 of 14] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.Pango.Types ( .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Graphics\Rendering\Pango\Types.hs, .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Graphics\Rendering\Pango\Types.o )
[ 2 of 14] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.Pango.BasicTypes ( .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Graphics\Rendering\Pango\BasicTypes.hs, .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Graphics\Rendering\Pango\BasicTypes.o )
[ 3 of 14] Compiling Graphics.Rendering.Pango.Structs ( .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Graphics\Rendering\Pango\Structs.hs, .stack-work\dist\i386-windows\Cabal-1.22.4.0\build\Graphics\Rendering\Pango\Structs.o )

GraphicsRenderingPangoStructs.hsc:79:21:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ÔÇÿWord420906795024ÔÇÖ

GraphicsRenderingPangoStructs.hsc:79:40:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ÔÇÿWord420906795024ÔÇÖ

GraphicsRenderingPangoStructs.hsc:79:59:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class ÔÇÿWord420906795024ÔÇÖ
```

It continues with a whole slew of nearly identical errors.

**EDIT** (cf. haoformayor's comment)

I encountered that error ticket before posting this question, but wasn't sure how to fix the `printf` issue 'cleanly'. I have tried following your advice, but I transitioned from cabal quite recently and am still not familiar with the basics of `stack`.

Having edited my stack.yaml file (see below), I was met with the very same list of error messages.

```
packages:
- location:
  git: https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs.git
  commit: dff5deae25a3f2c7d63ae583d1096b626bb6a9d2
```

I'll include additional information if necessary. Perhaps I've done something wrong?

**EDIT**
I've amended the `git` URL and removed a duplicated `packages` key in my `stack.yaml` file. `Stack` is now able to find the latest version of `gtk2hs` on GitHub, but complains about a missing `.cabal` file. Presumably I have to run it through some alternative build system (eg. `gtk2hs-buildtools`).

Comment: I don't have a Windows machine handy, so I can't verify, but I think you're running into this issue: https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/issues/110. Something with printf formatting C99 Windows upstream wibble wobble. Comments on that issue indicate that the Hackage package is broken on Windows, but fixed on the project's `master` branch. If that's the case, you should try adding https://github.com/gtk2hs/gtk2hs/ to your stack.yaml, so as to build from the bleeding edge. See http://docs.haskellstack.org/en/stable/yaml_configuration.html#packages for an example.